# flutter - Future<bool> convert to bool

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I have a future bool method and i want to use this method IconButton color. If i use below codes, i see a error message on my device screen **type'Future' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type of cast.**

```
Future<bool> ifExistInFavoriteList(String url) async {
```

bool ifExists = false;

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List my = (prefs.getStringList('myFavoriteList') ?? List());

my.contains(url) ? ifExists = true :  ifExists = false;

return ifExists;

}

```
  bool _isLiked() {
bool a = false;
a = ifExistInFavoriteList(widget.imageUrl) as bool;

return a;
```

}
}

```
Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                        color:
                            _isLiked() ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.green, 
                        icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                        onPressed: () {
                          //TO-DO
                        },
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just simply typecast a Future to bool. Either you need to use await or then syntax to get the bool value from that future. But I suggest you to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which will be the best solution.

```
FutureBuilder(future: ifExistInFavoriteList(widget.imageUrl),
              builder:(context, snapshot) {
    Color iconColor = Colors.green;
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
            iconColor = Colors.purple;
    }
    return IconButton(color: iconColor,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                      onPressed: () {
                         //TO-DO
                      },
           );
     },
),
```

Comment: If i use like this, icon color not changed. Could you please update your code.   onPressed: () {
                                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
                                  deleteFromFavoriteList(widget.imageUrl);
                                } else {
                                  saveFavoriteList(widget.imageUrl);
                                }

Comment: If i want to write a method in onPressed, IconColor not changed :(

Comment: Think about like button in instagram.

Comment: @jancooth : If you want to re-paint (I mean change the state of that button, based on the new values), You have two options, 1) Use setState to re-draw that widget. 2) Modify that future (First assign the future to a variable and use it in the future builder, if you re create and assign it to that variable, it will execute the code once again)

Comment: @jancooth Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170330/reload-data-when-using-futurebuilder

Answer (score 6):

A general answer.

Say this is your function which returns `Future<bool>`.

```dart
Future<bool> myFunc() async => true;
```

To get the `bool` value from it,

1. Use `async-await`

   ```dart
   void main() async {
     var value = await myFunc(); // value = true
   }
   ```
2. Use `then`:

   ```dart
   void main() {
     bool? value;
     myFunc().then((result) => value = result);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Yes because `ifExistInFavoriteList(String url)` is of type `Future<bool>`, you need to use FutureBuilder widget to get the bool value.

```
Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: ifExistInFavoriteList(widget.imageUrl),
          builder: (context, asyncSnapshot){
            if(asyncSnapshot.hasData){
              final _isLiked = asyncSnapshot.data;
              return IconButton(
                color:
                _isLiked() ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.green,
                icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                onPressed: () {
                  //TO-DO
                },
              );
            }
          return IconButton(
            color:Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            onPressed: () {
              //TO-DO
            },
          );
      },),
    ),
```