# Change state in FutureBuilder when the data is loaded

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I update the UI if I need to wait for the `FutureBuilder`? Do I need to call my future function twice, one for for the builder and one again to change the UI?

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getUserOrder(4045),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // I need to change the state at this point
            return Text("${snapshot.error}",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline);
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }),
```

Calling `setState` inside the `FutureBuilder` throws this error:

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

I don't need to display a button or any other other to be clicked. I want to perform the action automatically when the date is loaded in the `futureBuilder`

Comment: do you mean how to use state to retry the future if some error occurs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload data when using FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170330/reload-data-when-using-futurebuilder)

Comment: You may call `setState()`. But what is the goal?

Comment: You cannot call setState inside a futureBuilder (I'll add the error later)

Comment: update question with error

Comment: @easeccy that question is different. It displays a button and for my case I need to perform the action straight away

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't call setState inside `FutureBuilder` the solution was remove it and do something like this:

```
getBillingInfo() {
    Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false)
        .getBillingInfo(context)
        .then((billingInfo) {
      setState(() {
        if (billingInfo["companyInfo"] != null &&
            billingInfo["taxes"].isNotEmpty) {
          _canGenerateInvoices = true;
        } else {
          _canGenerateInvoices = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

...

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getBillingInfo();
  }
```

...

```
Visibility(
 visible: _canGenerateInvoices,
 child: MyWidget()
)
```

Having this, when I perform other actions I can always change the value of `_canGenerateInvoices`